# Identifying a schematic file and converting for use in Altium

Tags: schematics, software

I have a few schematic files which I need to open up in Altium, they are all *.sch files and when opened in Altium appear completely blank.
When opened with a text editor they do appear to have all correct information in there.

I have attached a small snippet of the file, but can upload one if required.

```
*P GCS_LTD
4 60 00000000
-3475, -1150, 4792, 4696, 25;
*R LASERNAV
*S4520B       
550 500
1,5,150,50,150,450,400,450,400,50,1,5,
150,350,232,350,232,150,150,150,1,5,232,250,
272,250,232,280,1,5,150,50,400,50;
7,2,150,250,
3,2,150,200,
3,2,150,100,
4,0,400,300,
4,0,400,250,
4,0,400,200,
4,0,400,150;
;
```

Comment: Altium has a number of native import options.   But you might have had to install them during program install.   They'll be found under file/import    Dig around a bit.    If you can't locate them, write back with what version you're using and I'll point you in the right direction

Comment: I have had a go with a few importers but nothing worked unfortunately.

Comment: Altium has a healthy user forum.   You'd probably be better posting there.    The fact your files are called *.SCH might be confusing the Importer because that's Altium's native naming scheme also (just a wild guess)

Comment: Cheers - I'll try posting over there!